# vertically align two different classes next to each other with css

Tags: css, class, vertical-alignment

How can I align two div's with different classes together above another?

If I have the following code:

```
<div class="div1">
</div>
<div class="div2">
</div>
<div class="div3">
</div>
```

how can I align div1 and div3 next to each other? and above the div1? Is it possible only with html and css?
thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve here. Post an image of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you reorder your html? Then this is easy. Otherwise you have to use flexbox as @ori drori mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap them with a flexbox container, and change the `order` of the elements:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
  order: 1;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

.div2 {
  order: 3;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.div3 {
  order: 2;
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
  1
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
  2
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
  3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just place all the div's in a container that is 100% width and do a text-align: center?

Simple [jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzfdahw0/) for you.

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```